# Add a new element to an array without specifying the index in Bash

Tags: bash, arrays

Is there a way to do something like PHPs `$array[] = 'foo';` in bash vs doing:

```
array[0]='foo'
array[1]='bar'
```

Comment: "[How to add/remove an element to/from the array in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/328882/72456)"

Answer (score 1901, accepted):

Yes there is:

```
ARRAY=()
ARRAY+=('foo')
ARRAY+=('bar')
```

[Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameters):

> In the context where an assignment statement is assigning a value to a shell variable or array index (see Arrays), the ‘+=’ operator can be used to append to or add to the variable's previous value.

Also:

> When += is applied to an  array  variable  using  compound  assignment  (see  Arrays below), the variable's value is not unset (as it is when using =), and new values are appended to the array beginning at one greater than the array's maximum index (for indexed arrays)

Comment: This works just fine with bash 3.2.48 (OS X 10.8.2). Note that `ARRAY` is just a placeholder for an actual variable name. Even if your array indices are _not_ sequential, appending with `+=` will simply assign to the highest index + 1.

Comment: Is there something like that in bash version 4.2.24(1)?

Comment: It is important to note, that ARRAY+=('foo') is way different than ARRAY+='foo', which appends the string 'foo' to the entry with the lowest(?) key.

Comment: According to http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/bashchanges, this syntax first appeared in version 3.1-alpha1.

Comment: Also, `ARRAY=( "${ARRAY[@]}" "new value" )`
works. But it sucks if array is empty and you set `set -u`. Note, that this syntax will not prepend empty element if array was empty. So, this syntax will help in older bashes

Comment: like TheConstructor said, also do not confuse ARRAY+=('foo') with "let ARRAY+=('foo')" which will just treat the first item (foo) as an integer of 0, and convert the first index into an integer type (-i), and add the value (which is zero, unless you passed a variable that was declared (ie, declare -i foo=4), then the value would have been added, even if you didn't put the $ on since 'let' evaluates just like the $(()).

Comment: why isn't it working for me? `:~/tmp$ myarray=(jj)
:~/tmp$ echo $myarray
jj
:~/tmp$ myarray+=(hh)
:~/tmp$ echo $myarray
jj
`

Comment: @TheConstructor: Good point; it is _always_ index `0` that is targeted when you do `ARRAY+='foo'`, irrespective of what the array's true lowest index is.

Comment: @Jas: To access the _entire_ array, you must use `${myarray[@]}` - referencing an array variable as if it were a scalar is the same as accessing its element 0; in other words: `$myarray` is the same as `${myarray[0]}`.

Comment: @socketpair The `ARRAY=( "${ARRAY[@]}" "new value" )` will re-number the index to the elements inside the `ARRAY`. That *is* a problem with sparse `ARRAY`s.

Comment: For anyone trying to add the output of a command to an array do not use `ARRAY+=$(<command>)`, instead use a variable to hold the command's output and then add it to the array `VAR="$(<command>)"; ARRAY+=("$VAR")`. In Bash 4 and higher `mapfile` can also be used, see @gniourf_gniourf's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32931403/2121777).

Comment: @Vito `ARRAY+=( $(command) )` would have been fine. `readarray`/`mapfile` are much more flexible of course

Comment: @AliIsmayilov and anyone else this isn't working for, make sure you're not [adding items in a subshell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22691436/unable-to-add-element-to-array-in-bash).

Comment: Is it possible to add multiple elements at once? For example, `ARRAY+=('foo' 'bar')` or `ARRAY+=('foo bar')`?

Comment: @MikeShiyan Yes, `ARRAY+=('foo' 'bar')` will work and will add the items `'foo'` and `'bar'`. `ARRAY+=('foo bar')` will add a single item `'foo bar'`.

Comment: Adding elements this way to Associative array will not work in GNU bash, version 4.4.23(1)-release.

Comment: All please: **Do not** ask additional question and provide answers to such questions *as comments* when they are not covered by the original question. Instead **ask a new question** then, or preferably: *Look if such a question and answer already exists*.

Answer (score 97):

As **Dumb Guy** points out, it's important to note whether the array starts at zero and is sequential. Since you can make assignments to and unset non-contiguous indices `${#array[@]}` is not always the next item at the end of the array.

```
$ array=(a b c d e f g h)
$ array[42]="i"
$ unset array[2]
$ unset array[3]
$ declare -p array     # dump the array so we can see what it contains
declare -a array='([0]="a" [1]="b" [4]="e" [5]="f" [6]="g" [7]="h" [42]="i")'
$ echo ${#array[@]}
7
$ echo ${array[${#array[@]}]}
h
```

Here's how to get the last index:

```
$ end=(${!array[@]})   # put all the indices in an array
$ end=${end[@]: -1}    # get the last one
$ echo $end
42
```

That illustrates how to get the last element of an array. You'll often see this:

```
$ echo ${array[${#array[@]} - 1]}
g
```

As you can see, because we're dealing with a sparse array, this isn't the last element. This works on both sparse and contiguous arrays, though:

```
$ echo ${array[@]: -1}
i
```

Comment: Great stuff; never knew that substring-extraction syntax could be applied to arrays too; the rules, determined by trial and error, are (bash 3.2.48):
`${array[@]: start[:count]}`
Returns count elems. or, if not specified, all _remaining_ elems. starting at the following elem.:
- If start >= 0: from the elem. whose index is >= start.
- If start < 0: from the elem. whose index is (last array index + 1) - abs(start);
CAVEAT: if abs(start) > (last array index + 1), a null string is returned.
If count is specified, as many elements are returned, even if their indices are not contiguous from start.

Comment: @mklement: In Bash 4.2, you can use negative array subscripts to access elements counting from the end of the array. `${array[-1]}`

Comment: That's good to know, thanks. OS X (as of 10.8.2) still uses 3.2.48, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418616/does-darwin-macos-modify-bash tells me that, unfortunately, "Apple use quite an old version of Bash, as they don't ship code that's licensed under GPL3."

Answer (score 68):

```
$ declare -a arr
$ arr=("a")
$ arr=("${arr[@]}" "new")
$ echo ${arr[@]}
a new
$ arr=("${arr[@]}" "newest")
$ echo ${arr[@]}
a new newest
```

Comment: nice for bash versions that do not support the semantics of += operator explained by e-t172

Comment: a good backward-compatible solution, but beware that if any of the existing elements have spaces in them, they will be split into multiple elements; use `arr=("${arr[@]}" "new")` if you have elements with spaces in them

Comment: This can also be used to push in front of the array, which is just what I need.

Comment: If your array has hundreds of long strings, then the `+=` variant is probably much more efficient.

Answer (score 37):

If your array is always sequential and starts at 0, then you can do this:

```
array[${#array[@]}]='foo'

# gets the length of the array
${#array_name[@]}
```

If you inadvertently use spaces between the equal sign:

```
array[${#array[@]}] = 'foo'
```

Then you will receive an error similar to:

```
array_name[3]: command not found
```

Comment: Yes, you can, but the `+=` syntax (see @e-t172's answer) is (a) simpler, and (b) also works with arrays that are non-contiguous and/or do not start with 0.

Comment: Honestly this solution (for me) is working better thant the "+=", because with the latter the length is sometimes wrong (increases by two when adding one element)... so I prefer this reply! :)

Comment: This also works in earlier versions of bash, before `+=` was added, eg version 2

Comment: This also works when your elements have spaces in them - `$arr += ($el)` seemed to split the string by space and add each of the elements.

Answer (score 11):

With an indexed array, you can to something like this:

```
declare -a a=()
a+=('foo' 'bar')
```

Answer (score 3):

also check this out :

```
test_array=(1 2 3 4)
test_array+=(5)
echo "${test_array[@]}"
```

Result : `1 2 3 4 5`

the `+=` operator can be used to append a single element or multiple elements to an array, in instance, you can append more elements to the array like this:

```
test_array+=(6 7 8 9)
echo "${test_array[@]}"
```

Result : `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`

I wanna mention that you can also remove an element from an array in Bash without specifying the index, you can use the `unset` command with the element's value

```
test_array=(1 2 3 4 5)
unset test_array[2]
echo "${test_array[@]}"
```

Result : `1 2 4 5`

be careful, when you remove an element from an array, the indices of the remaining elements will be adjusted accordingly. In the example above, when I remove the third element with the value `3`, the fourth and fifth elements become the new third and fourth elements, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Append **element**:

```
array+=("${element}")
```

Append another **array**:

```
array+=("${array[@]}")
```

Append command **output**:

```
readarray -t output < <(command)
array+=("${output[@]}")
```