# Does Darwin/MacOS modify Bash?

Tags: macos, bash, portability

I'm wondering about the portability of Bash scripts that use Bash built-in commands.

I understand that each flavor of UNIX tends to modify various UNIX utilities. But do they tend to leave Bash and Bash built-ins alone? What about MacOS in particular?

Comment: I think so. Bash has been around for a long time, is very very stable at this point, and isn't adding new functionality. So why would anyone mess with it???

Comment: @ControlAltDel: Actually, some significant functionality was added in bash v4.0 (e.g. associative arrays) that OS X's version (3.2) doesn't have.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, bash is unmodified on Mac OS X (aside from minor tweaks required  to make it compile; you can review the source on http://opensource.apple.com/), and scripts should be quite portable.

As Graham Lee & Gordon Davisson point out, Mac OS X ships with older versions and there are differences between supported versions. Bash 4 has associative arrays and [other changes](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/bash4). Bash 3 includes regular expression matching (and probably others that I haven't searched for). Can't remember the Bash 2 differences, maybe some bracketing/conditional test differences?

Mac OS X 10.7.x Lion includes Bash 3.2.x. I don't recall the exact versions off the top of my head, but Mac OS X 10.6.x Snow Leopard & 10.5.x Leopard include Bash 3.x. Mac OS X 10.4.x Tiger and earlier used Bash 2.0.5. So, you'll definitely run into differences between what's supported by default.

Naturally, beyond the differences between feature sets & built-ins for the different `bash` versions on Mac OS X , you'll also find differences in other tools. For example, there are `getopt` issues on Mac OS X (spaces, which are frequently found in Mac OS X directory/file paths, are not supported in arguments; the built-in `getopts` in newer `bash` versions can help with this, but may not be available in older versions). Naturally, there will be other tools that have different functionalities or syntaxes as well.

I'm definitely not an expert `bash` developer, but I've written a *number* of Mac OS X-specific scripts that support various releases. See my [Regular Expressions in Bash and Alternatives](http://www.makkintosshu.com/journal/regular-expressions-in-bash-and-alternatives) article for discussion of the 2.x vs 3.x regular expression features and workarounds. Or, some of my `bash` scripts which have taken Mac OS X into heavy consideration: [tools-osx](https://github.com/morgant/tools-osx) & [bash_stub](https://github.com/morgant/bash_stub).

Answer (score 3):

Apple use quite an old version of Bash, as they don't ship code that's licensed under GPL3. You can download the current version [from Apple's open source site](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/bash/bash-84/), and see that it at least claims to be vanilla Bash 3.2 (though obviously the Xcode project has been added).

Comment: can't seem to find any notes from the darwin devs, so maybe it's stock.  I wish there were a definite way to know though.

Answer (score 0):

bash version 4 is not shipping on Darwin or MacOS Lion.
so the mac does not support the improvements to the read command, etc which is unfortunate.

cygwin has bash 4.1.10

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: The questioner asked about the bash and MacOS.
Don't hold your breath waiting for Apple to use the most recent version of bash.

Comment: as of Mar 5, 2017, Apple is shipping
GNU bash,version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin16)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
So basically a decade behind.