# Reading filenames into an array

Tags: bash, unix, cygwin

I want to get a list of files and then read the results into an array where each array element corresponds to a file name. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  Maybe not advisable if the names might contain arbitrary characters (spaces and newlines in the names cause grief), but it is doable.  Which bit of the manual did you have difficulty understanding?

Comment: How is the _list_ being defined? bash has arrays, but depending on how the list is generated, different techniquest are better than others.  In any case, post also your own attempts to solve the problem.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Don't use `ls`, it's [not intended](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) for this purpose. Use globbing.

```
shopt -s nullglob
array=(*)
array2=(file*)
array3=(dir/*)
```

The `nullglob` option causes the array to be empty if there are no matches.

Comment: Thanks, Is there anyway I can pipe the results of these? I tried something like arr(* | grep ".txt") but it does not like it.

Comment: @dublintech: You don't need `grep`, just include the string in your glob: `array=(*.txt)` or `array=(*foo*)`

Comment: You can also [append filenames](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1951523/712334) to an array, [output filenames](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15692004/712334) and [loop through](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8880633/712334) them.

Comment: To my pleasant surprise, this also works with filenames that have whitespace or special characters in them! Tested with GNU bash, version 5.0.

Answer (score 33):

Following will create an array arr with ls output in current directory:

```
arr=( $(ls) )
```

Though using output of `ls` is not safe at all.

Much better and safer than `ls` you can use `echo *`:

```
arr=( * )

echo ${#arr[@]} # will echo number of elements in array

echo "${arr[@]}" # will dump all elements of the array
```

Comment: `ls` is not necessary and should not be used for this purpose.

Comment: Agreed, I just wanted to tell how to create an array from some command output. However I edited my answer to stress that `ls` output should be avoided.

Comment: When the array expansion is not quoted, all elements of the array are represented as a string, rather than individual elements of the array. Unquoted `${arr[*]}` and `${arr[@]}` are the same.

Comment: Does anyone knows what is the max number of filenames / elements an array can hold?

Comment: anubhava, please remove your `arr=( $(ls) )` line. Or if you want to leave it, please explicitly add a mention like **don't do this, it's broken.**

Answer (score 4):

In bash you can create an array of filenames with *pathname expansion (globbing)* like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
SOURCE_DIR=path/to/source
files=(
   "$SOURCE_DIR"/*.tar.gz
   "$SOURCE_DIR"/*.tgz
   "$SOURCE_DIR"/**/*
)
```

The above will create an array called `files` and add to it N array elements, where each element in the array corresponds to an item in `SOURCE_DIR` ending in `.tar.gz` or `.tgz`, or any item in a subdirectory thereof with subdirectory recursion possible as Dennis [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10981439/reading-filenames-into-an-array/51683629?noredirect=1#comment90332542_51683629) in the comments.

You can then use `printf` to see the contents of the array including paths:

```
printf '%s\n' "${files[@]}" # i.e. path/to/source/filename.tar.gz
```

Or using *parameter substitution* to exclude the pathnames:

```
printf '%s\n' "${files[@]##*/}" # i.e. filename.tgz
```

Comment: You need to have `shopt -s globstar` in order to use recursive globbing (`**`).

Comment: Not for me. And the default Bash on MacOS is 3.2 which does not have `globstar`. What does counting the characters in some directory names with `echo /usr/**/ | wc -c` output for you? On my Mac, in Sierra with Bash 3.2 or in Bash 4.4 with `globstar` off, it outputs 122. If I run Bash 4.4 with `globstar` on, I get 277904. The latter is clearly recursive and the former is not. BTW, `shopt` is defined, but I presume you mean `globstar` (in Bash 3.2, `shopt -p globstar` gives an error, in Bash 4.4 it shows whether it's set or unset).

Comment: `hash` only works with external executables (try `hash -t ls` and `help hash`) and isn't going to show anything for `shopt` because it's a builtin or for `globstar` because it's an option rather than an executable. Try `type -a shopt` to show where `shopt` is coming from and `shopt` by itself to show the settings of all your options. Use `echo "$BASH_VERSION"` to show the version of your currently running shell (if it's Bash) and look at the output of `ps -o tty,command` to see if it's actually `/bin/bash`. Compare `find /usr -type d | wc -l` and `echo /usr/**/ | tr -cd " " | wc -c` ...

Comment: ... the counts should be fairly close if recursive globbing is working. My counts are in the neighborhood of 3800.

Comment: I'm ok with leaving it here. It's not specific to the OP's question, but it's a useful technique when outputting file names/paths.

Comment: Yes `globstar` was added in Bash 4.0. I still don't understand how `hash shopt` does anything useful for you since `shopt` is a builtin. And `hash` isn't intended to show whether something is defined - it shows whether the path to an external executable has been cached (or manipulates the cache). To find whether (and how) something is defined, use `type -a`. Also don't use `which` or `whereis` since they are external and know nothing about builtins, functions and aliases.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, `ls` isn't the way to go. Try this:

```
declare -a FILELIST
for f in *; do 
    #FILELIST[length_of_FILELIST + 1]=filename
    FILELIST[${#FILELIST[@]}+1]=$(echo "$f");
done
```

To get a filename from the array use:

```
echo ${FILELIST[x]}
```

To get n filenames from the array starting from x use:

```
echo ${FILELIST[@]:x:n}
```

For a great tutorial on bash arrays, see:
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/bash-array-tutorial/

Comment: You should iterate over the file glob *OR* create an array using a file glob as in my answer - not *both*!. When adding elements to an array, there's no reason to use the length of the array in a complex index expression (it won't work as expected if the array is sparse, for one thing). `array+=(element)`. There's no reason to use `$(echo "$f")` just do the assignment directly. There's a missing closing curly brace on one of your `echo` statements.

Comment: are you aware that what you're doing is a broken way to just do `FILELIST = ( * )`? (or, rather `FILELIST += ( * )`). Why on earth do you use `$(echo "$f")` instead of just `"$f"`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
path="" # could set to any absolute path
declare -a array=( "${path}"/* )
```

I'm assuming you'll pull out the unwanted stuff from the list later.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a more specific file listing that cannot be returned through globbing, then you can use process substitution for the `find` command with a `while` loop delimited with null characters.

Example:

```
files=()
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' f; do
    files+=("$f")
done < <(find . -type f -name '*.dat' -size +1G -print0)
```