# Bash Script Reading Files of a directory into Array

Tags: bash

I am having trouble reading file into an array in bash.

I have noticed that people do not recommend using the ls -1 option.
Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more about what you are trying to do?  The ls command is for listing a directory, not reading files

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading filenames into an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10981439/reading-filenames-into-an-array)

Answer (score 17):

The most reliable way to get a list of files is with a shell wildcard:

```
# First set bash option to avoid
# unmatched patterns expand as result values
shopt -s nullglob
# Then store matching file names into array
filearray=( * )
```

If you need to get the files somewhere other than the current directory, use:

```
filearray=( "$dir"/* )
```

Note that the directory path should be in double-quotes in case it contains spaces or other special characters, but the `*` cannot be or it won't be expanded into a file list. Also, this fills the array with the paths to the files, not just the names (e.g. if `$dir` is "path/to/directory", filearray will contain "path/to/directory/file1", "path/to/directory/file2", etc). If you want just the file names, you can trim the path prefixes with:

```
filearray=( "$dir"/* )
filearray=( "${filearray[@]##*/}" )
```

If you need to include files in subdirectories, things get a bit more complicated; see [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116992/capturing-output-of-find-print0-into-a-bash-array/1120952#1120952).

Comment: I am in the directory of the array. So, the first one **filearray=( * )** this will get all of the files into the array with each file having their own index?

Comment: @sinful15: Yes. BTW, be sure to put references to the filenames in doublequotes, as in `"${filearray[1]}"` for just one file or `"${filearray[@]}"` for the full list.

Comment: Awesome answer, helped a ton!

Comment: Thanks... 3 hours searching how to use vars as directories path. Thanks a lot!