# Print array elements on separate lines in Bash?

Tags: arrays, bash

How do I print the array element of a Bash array on separate lines? This one works, but surely there is a better way:

```
$ my_array=(one two three)
$ for i in ${my_array[@]}; do echo $i; done
one
two
three
```

Tried this one but it did not work:

```
$ IFS=$'\n' echo ${my_array[*]}
one two three
```

Comment: in zsh `print -l $path`

Answer (score 637, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
$ printf '%s\n' "${my_array[@]}"
```

The difference between `$@` and `$*`:

- Unquoted, the results are unspecified. In Bash, both expand to separate args
  and then wordsplit and globbed.
- Quoted, `"$@"` expands each element as a separate argument, while `"$*"`
  expands to the args merged into one argument: `"$1c$2c..."` (where `c` is
  the first char of `IFS`).

You almost always want `"$@"`. Same goes for `"${arr[@]}"`.

**Always double quote them!**

Comment: And note, the double quotes around the variable reference are important if you want to make sure elements with internal spaces aren't inadvertently split up.

Comment: Consider [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/767579/334715) question.

Answer (score 97):

Just quote the argument to echo:

```bash
(IFS=$'\n'; echo "${my_array[*]}")
```

the sub shell helps restoring the IFS after use

Comment: sorry perreal, I moved my check mark to sputnick, despite liking your solution better, just because I learned about the 'printf' function.

Comment: Thanks for this answer - I like it!  Too bad assignments happen after expansion so `IFS=$'\n' echo "${my_array[*]}"` doesn't work.  Oh well!

Comment: @cxw, what do you mean by "assignments happen"?

Comment: @bschlueter, I tried with Bash 4 — 4.4.23(1)-release — and it works!

Comment: @StevenShaw [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Simple-Command-Expansion.html) - in my example, bash saves the `IFS=...` (linked #1), then expands `"${my_array[*]}"` (#2), _then_ changes `IFS` (#4).  As a result, you can't do this in one command - you need the IFS change first, so you need a subshell `( ... )` unless you are willing to change IFS in your current shell.

Comment: @cxw Ah, I didn't see what you were trying to do there. I think it doesn't work because `echo` is a builtin in Bash. However, you can wrap it in a function and it will work! https://gist.github.com/steshaw/53ba0095bce8ccab52d26a14375dedb8

Comment: I do like the `printf` solution though. I hadn't realised that, as the Bash manual points out, "The format is reused as necessary to consume all of the arguments". It's a bit counterintuitive for C programmers, however .

Comment: @StevenShaw good idea - I hadn't thought of using a function.  It's not because `echo` is a builtin, though.  It's because the function in your gist includes the expansion, so the expansion doesn't happen until after the function is called, by which point `IFS` has already been changed.

Comment: @cxw, Bash is a bit nasty, isn't it?

Answer (score 63):

Using *for*:

```
for each in "${alpha[@]}"
do
  echo "$each"
done
```

Using *history*; note this will fail if your values contain `!`:

```
history -p "${alpha[@]}"
```

Using *basename*; note this will fail if your values contain `/`:

```
basename -a "${alpha[@]}"
```

Using *shuf*; note that results might not come out in order:

```
shuf -e "${alpha[@]}"
```

Comment: "shuf"... "might not come out in order"... hilarious.

Comment: for shuf. Who would have thought to use that?

Comment: `histchars= history -p "${alpha[@]}"` should work all the time

Answer (score 7):

Another useful variant is pipe to `tr`:

`echo "${my_array[@]}" | tr ' ' '\n'`

This looks simple and compact

Comment: Except this breaks on `my_array=( "one two" three )`

Comment: Fixed it with double quotes.

Comment: Didn't work as advertised on Bash version `4`+, had to use `echo "${my_array[@]}" | tr '' ' \n'`, though personally I'd avoid using `echo` like that, where `tr` my choice I think something like _`tr '' ' \n' <<<"${my_array[@]}"`_ might be a bit easier to read later.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a Bash C Style For Loop to do what you want.

```
my_array=(one two three)

for ((i=0; i < ${#my_array[@]}; i++ )); do echo "${my_array[$i]}"; done
one
two
three
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried the answers here in a giant for...if loop, but didn't get any joy - so I did it like this, maybe messy but did the job:

```
 # EXP_LIST2 is iterated    
 # imagine a for loop
     EXP_LIST="List item"    
     EXP_LIST2="$EXP_LIST2 \n $EXP_LIST"
 done 
 echo -e $EXP_LIST2
```

although that added a space to the list, which is fine - I wanted it indented a bit.
Also presume the "\n" could be printed in the original $EP_LIST.

Comment: Doesn't look like a complete example.

Answer (score 3):

In zsh one can use the built-in command  `print -l $path`

Answer (score 1):

I've discovered that you can use eval to avoid using a subshell. Thus:

```
IFS=$'\n' eval 'echo "${my_array[*]}"'
```

Comment: Never ever use the _evil_ eval

Comment: That is just nonsense. Just never use evil eval on user input.