# bash: 'error: value too great for base (error token is ''2M'')'

Tags: arrays, bash

I am trying to print an array which contains string elements. Some are words, some are number and some have both. I get the error in the title. I know this error is usually linked to the shell thinking I am using a base other than decimal. this time the problem token is a combination of letters and numbers (2M)

```
arrcourse=[$[`cat tmp2`]]
    size=${#arrcourse[@]}
    for(( j=1; j<$size; j++ )); do
        echo ${arrcourse[$j]}
    done
```

tmp2 is the file the contains the line I ultimately wanna print (I use and array to lose the spaces and later to choose which elements to print).

Comment: i guess. i am very confused by the use of parenthessis in bash (new to scripts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line looks suspicious. Arrays are created with parenthesis `()`, not braces `[]`. Did you want to write one of the following commands instead?

```
arrcourse=(`cat tmp2`)
arrcourse=( $(cat tmp2) )
```

The commands are equivalent. `$()` is preferred over backticks because it can be nested.

**Hint:** Bash also has a command to read arrays.

```
read -ra arrcourse < tmp2
```

Comment: @doronbs11 Glad I could help. Please accept the answer that solved your problem (click the checkmark on the left of an answer) to close your question.

Comment: I'd recommend the `read` option -- using `$( )` without double-quotes around it doesn't just split it into "words" based on whitespace (spaces, tabs, and newlines, assuming you haven't changed `$IFS`), it also tries to expand anything that looks like a shell wildcard into a list of matching filenames. This can have really weird effects. (And, of course, if you do use double-quotes, it won't be word-split and you just get the entire file as one huge array element.)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do this?

`printf '%s\n' "${my_array[@]}"`

Source: [bash print array elements on separate lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15691942/bash-print-array-elements-on-separate-lines)