# Awk output not consistent

Tags: bash, awk

I have created a bash script that is suppose to either append or overwrite some existing environment variables in /etc/environment. The script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a array=("http_proxy=http://username:password@proxy:8080"
                  "https_proxy=http://username:password@proxy:8080"
                  "ftp_proxy=ftp://username:password@proxy:8080"
                  "no_proxy=\"localhost, 127.0.0.1\""
                 )

for i in "${array[@]}"; do
        awk -v var="${i%%=*}" '$0 !~ var' /etc/environment > /etc/environment
        echo "$i" >> /etc/environment
done
```

Given the following input (/etc/environment):

```
http_proxy=http://otheruser:password@otherproxy:8080
https_proxy=http://username:password@proxy:8080
some_env_varible=some_value
```

I expect the following output:

```
http_proxy=http://username:password@proxy:8080
https_proxy=http://username:password@proxy:8080
ftp_proxy=ftp://username:password@proxy:8080
no_proxy="localhost, 127.0.0.1"
some_env_variable=some_value
```

However i get the following output:

```
http_proxy=http://username:password@proxy:8080
https_proxy=http://username:password@proxy:8080
ftp_proxy=ftp://username:password@proxy:8080
no_proxy="localhost, 127.0.0.1"
```

Running the awk command outside of the script seems to work fine, returning only the lines that do not match a specific environment variable. I am puzzled to why this is not working inside this script.

## Update

As per request:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/environment
http_proxy=http://username:password@proxy:8080
https_proxy=http://username:password@proxy:8080
ftp_proxy=ftp://username:password@proxy:8080
no_proxy="localhost, 127.0.0.1"
$ i="http_proxy=http://username2:password2@proxy:8080"
$ sudo awk -v var="${i%%=*}" '$0 !~ var' /etc/environment
https_proxy=http://username:password@proxy:8080
ftp_proxy=ftp://username:password@proxy:8080
no_proxy="localhost, 127.0.0.1"
```

Comment: `awk ... /etc/environment > /etc/environment` is no good idea.

Comment: Please post the *awk command outside of the script*, I doubt it could *work fine* (as pointed out by @Cyrus).

Comment: To check whether the variable exists: `if ! grep -q "${i%%=*}" file; then echo "$i" >> /etc/environment; fi`.

Comment: @simlev check the update. Notice that the purpose is also to overwrite existing variables, and not just append if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks a bit cumbersome what you are trying to achieve, you might want to consider any of the following options:

**updating the original script:**

The awk line you write tries to print everything which is not in the file `/etc/environment`. This is exactly what `grep -v` does :

```
for i in "${array[@]}"; do
   grep -v "${i%%=*}" /etc/environment > /etc/environment.new
   echo "$i" >> /etc/environment.new
   mv /etc/environment.new /etc/environment
done
```

**Exploit the power of `grep`:**

Now that we use `grep`, you should be aware of the flag

> **`-f FILE, --file=FILE`** Obtain patterns from `FILE`, one per line.  The empty file contains zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing.

So, making use of process-substitution (`<(command)`), you can now do something like:

```
grep -v -f <(printf "%s\n" "${array[@]}" | cut -d= -f1) -F /etc/environment > /etc/environment.new
printf "%s\n" "${array[@]}" >> /etc/environment.new
mv /etc/environment.new /etc/environment
```

Here we use `printf "%s\n" "${array[@]}"` to print the array on a new line (cfr [bash print array elements on separate lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15691942/bash-print-array-elements-on-separate-lines)) and we use the `cut` command to retrieve everything before `=`.

**Just use a single `awk`:**

When you think of combinations of `grep`, `cut`, `awk`, `sed`, `tr`, ... you generally can replace it with a single `awk`. We will use `awk` to read 2 files. The first is `/etc/environment` and the second is the file we can generate from the `printf` command. We will use an awk array in which we store the values per `key` where the `key` is the part before the `=`. So the `=`-sign will be our delimiter.  Furthermore, if we encounter a variable with an identical key, it will be overwritten. This allows us to update the values with new values.

```
awk -F'=' '{a[$1]=$0}END{for(i in a) print a[i] }' /etc/environment <(printf "%s\n" "${array[@]}")
```

If you don't really use the array further in your script, you can just use a HERE document to achieve the same:

```
cat - <<EOF awk -F'=' '{a[$1]=$0}END{for(i in a) print a[i] }' /etc/environment -
http_proxy=http://username:password@proxy:8080
https_proxy=http://username:password@proxy:8080
ftp_proxy=ftp://username:password@proxy:8080
no_proxy="localhost, 127.0.0.1"
EOF
```