# Print associative array keys on separate lines in Bash?

Tags: arrays, bash, associative-array

Similar to this [Print array elements on separate lines in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15691942/print-array-elements-on-separate-lines-in-bash) but printing only the keys.

The answer on that other one `%s\n' "${myarray[@]}"` when used on an associative array prints the values only while I'm looking for the keys.

```sh
declare -r -A myarray=(
   [a]=1
   [b]=2
   [c]=3
   [d]=4
)
```

Would like to have:

```
a
b
c
d
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So just:

```
printf "%s\n" "${!myarray[@]}"
```