# Sorting output of find inside a loop

Tags: linux, sorting, unix, find, sh

This is my first post on StackOverflow, so please be gentle.

What I am trying to do is to sort the output of find by size (from greatest to smallest).

I have a file.txt which contains:

```
file1
file2
file3
file4
file5
file6
```

My code looks like this:

```
for x in $(cat file.txt)
do
find -name $x -printf '%s %p\n'| sort -rn
done
```

But instead the output is not sorted.

The output is the path of the files (which is great) and their sizes in the same order as in the file.

For example:

```
 128  /dir1/file1
 8 /dir2/file2
 0 file3
 4 file4
 ...
 and so on
```

Comment: Your loop works on each line in the text file.  So you are passing `sort` 1 file each time, in the order of the text file.  Sorry can't suggest how to fix it, but hope that helps understand whats going on.  I would guess an array might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10981439/reading-filenames-into-an-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call to `find` prints a single line for each file, which you then send to `sort`. Since `sort` only gets a single line each time you call it, there is nothing to sort, and the files are output in the order they are listed in in `file.txt`.

Instead, pipe the output from the entire loop to `sort`:

```
for x in $(cat file.txt)
do
find -name $x -printf '%s %p\n'
done| sort -rn
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, sir. You have been very helpful :)