# Problem getting an array of filenames which contain whitespaces in Bash

Tags: bash, scripting

I want to write a bash script and I need to get the filenames in a directory and I've done this :

```
list=`ls -p -m -1 $dir | grep -v /`
list=`echo $list | tr ' ' ','`
IFS=',' read -ra list_array <<< $list
```

If no file with whitespaces in the current directory exists , then the variable `list_array` holds the correct space-seperated array of filenames :

```
 $ echo "${list_array[*]}"
 a a.rar a.tar a.zip blah blah blah
```

But that wouldn't work correctly in situations where there exists some files with whitespaces in their names.To mitigate this , I changed that as follows :

```
list=`ls -p -m  $dir | grep -v /`     #This doesn't work in for filenames without whitespace
IFS=',' read -ra list_array <<< $list
```

But now `list_array` only holds the name of the first file.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading filenames into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10981439/reading-filenames-into-an-array)

Comment: Also see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use newlines as IFS.

```
IFS=$'\n'
list_array=(`ls -p -m -1 . | grep -v /`)
```