# Store two filenames into a variable which can be easily accessed by index 0 and 1

Tags: string, bash, shell, arraylist, sh

I have two filenames that I would like to store in a Bash variable :

For this, I did :

```
$ b=$(ls Fisher_GCph_WL_XSAF_COLUMN*PESS_F*gamma_*)
```

I get the variable `b` equal to :

```
$ echo $b
Fisher_GCph_WL_XSAF_COLUMN2_2_PESS_F_FoM_33.22_gamma_0.071.txt
Fisher_GCph_WL_XSAF_COLUMN2_2_PESS_F_FoM_71.91_gamma_N.txt
```

I want to build an array of 2 elements containing the 2 filenames above.

I tried to access them by :

```
$d eclare -a b
$ echo ${b[0]}
```

returns nothing

and

`$ echo ${b[1]}` returns `F`

What to do to have an array of string where I could access directly to first or second filename by index `0` or `1` ?

Comment: Do the answers to ["Reading filenames into an array"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10981439/reading-filenames-into-an-array) cover your question? (Also, what shell are you using? What you describe does not match bash's normal behavior.)

Comment: Which shell do you use?

Comment: Sounds like you're using zsh, not bash.

Comment: You don't need `ls` here. The glob itself generates the two file names, which is why `ls` receives them as arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need a simple array assignment and globbing.

```
shopt -s nullglob
b=(Fisher_GCph_WL_XSAF_COLUMN*PESS_F*gamma_*)
```

Comment: Just to add about `shopt -s nullglob`: depending on the context, saving + restoring `nullglob` might be a good idea

Answer (score 1):

The index notation you use is correct. The issue here **b** is not an array but a multiline string.

To declare a true array:

```
b=("Fisher_GCph_WL_XSAF_COLUMN2_2_PESS_F_FoM_33.22_gamma_0.071.txt" "Fisher_GCph_WL_XSAF_COLUMN2_2_PESS_F_FoM_71.91_gamma_N.txt")
```

NOTE - no comma between elements

bash treats **b** as an array:

```
declare -a b='([0]="Fisher_GCph_WL_XSAF_COLUMN2_2_PESS_F_FoM_33.22_gamma_0.071.txt" [1]="Fisher_GCph_WL_XSAF_COLUMN2_2_PESS_F_FoM_71.91_gamma_N.txt")'
```

Compare that to return from ls:

> ```
> $ c=$(ls)
> $ declare -p c
> declare -- c="Fisher_GCph_WL_XSAF_COLUMN2_2_PESS_F_FoM_33.22_gamma_0.071.txt
> Fisher_GCph_WL_XSAF_COLUMN2_2_PESS_F_FoM_71.91_gamma_N.txt"
> ```

In your case I would

1. Create an intermediate file:

> ```
> ls -1 > filelist
> ```

This is 'one' not 'l' - one row per file

2. Convert file into array:

> ```
> $mapfile -t b < filelist
> ```

3. Validate b is an array:

> ```
> $ declare -p b
> ```

4. Use the array:

> ```
> echo  ${b[1]}
> ```