# Reading output of a command into an array in Bash

Tags: arrays, bash

I need to read the output of a command in my script into an array. The command is, for example:

```
ps aux | grep | grep | x
```

and it gives the output line by line like this:

```
10
20
30
```

I need to read the values from the command output into an array, and then I will do some work if the size of the array is less than three.

Comment: Hey @barp, ANSWER YOUR QUESTIONS, lest your type be a drain on the entire community.

Comment: @James the issue's not with the fact that he's not answering his question... this is a Q/A site. He just didn't *mark* them as answered. He should mark them. Hint. @ barp

Comment: Please @barp, mark the question as answered.

Comment: Related: [Looping through the content of a file in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41646525/6862601) since reading the output of a command through process substitution is similar to reading from a file.

Answer (score 240):

The other answers will break if output of command contains spaces (which is rather frequent) or glob characters like `*`, `?`, `[...]`.

To get the output of a command in an array, with one line per element, there are essentially 3 ways:

1. With Bash≥4 use `mapfile`—it's the most efficient:

   ```
   mapfile -t my_array < <( my_command )
   ```
2. Otherwise, a loop reading the output (slower, but safe):

   ```
   my_array=()
   while IFS= read -r line; do
       my_array+=( "$line" )
   done < <( my_command )
   ```
3. As suggested by Charles Duffy in the comments (thanks!), the following might perform better than the loop method in number 2:

   ```
   IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a my_array < <( my_command && printf '\0' )
   ```

   Please make sure you use exactly this form, i.e., make sure you have the following:

   - `IFS=$'\n'` *on the same line as the `read` statement:* this will only set the environment variable `IFS` *for the `read` statement only.* So it won't affect the rest of your script at all. The purpose of this variable is to tell `read` to break the stream at the EOL character `\n`.
   - `-r`: this is important. It tells `read` *to not interpret the backslashes as escape sequences.*
   - `-d ''`: please note the space between the `-d` option and its argument `''`. If you don't leave a space here, the `''` will never be seen, as it will disappear in the *quote removal* step when Bash parses the statement. This tells `read` to stop reading at the nil byte. Some people write it as `-d $'\0'`, but it is not really necessary. `-d ''` is better.
   - `-a my_array` tells `read` to populate the array `my_array` while reading the stream.
   - You must use the `printf '\0'` statement *after* `my_command`, so that `read` returns `0`; it's actually not a big deal if you don't (you'll just get an return code `1`, which is okay if you don't use `set -e` – which you shouldn't anyway), but just bear that in mind. It's cleaner and more semantically correct. Note that this is different from `printf ''`, which doesn't output anything. `printf '\0'` prints a null byte, needed by `read` to happily stop reading there (remember the `-d ''` option?).

---

If you can, i.e., if you're sure your code will run on Bash≥4, use the first method. And you can see it's shorter too.

If you want to use `read`, the loop (method 2) might have an advantage over method 3 if you want to do some processing as the lines are read: you have direct access to it (via the `$line` variable in the example I gave), and you also have access to the lines already read (via the array `${my_array[@]}` in the example I gave).

Note that `mapfile` provides a way to have a callback eval'd on each line read, and in fact you can even tell it to only call this callback every *N* lines read; have a look at `help mapfile` and the options `-C` and `-c` therein. (My opinion about this is that it's a little bit clunky, but can be used sometimes if you only have simple things to do — I don't really understand why this was even implemented in the first place!).

---

Now I'm going to tell you why the following method:

```
my_array=( $( my_command) )
```

is broken when there are spaces:

```
$ # I'm using this command to test:
$ echo "one two"; echo "three four"
one two
three four
$ # Now I'm going to use the broken method:
$ my_array=( $( echo "one two"; echo "three four" ) )
$ declare -p my_array
declare -a my_array='([0]="one" [1]="two" [2]="three" [3]="four")'
$ # As you can see, the fields are not the lines
$
$ # Now look at the correct method:
$ mapfile -t my_array < <(echo "one two"; echo "three four")
$ declare -p my_array
declare -a my_array='([0]="one two" [1]="three four")'
$ # Good!
```

Then some people will then recommend using `IFS=$'\n'` to fix it:

```
$ IFS=$'\n'
$ my_array=( $(echo "one two"; echo "three four") )
$ declare -p my_array
declare -a my_array='([0]="one two" [1]="three four")'
$ # It works!
```

But now let's use another command, with *globs*:

```
$ echo "* one two"; echo "[three four]"
* one two
[three four]
$ IFS=$'\n'
$ my_array=( $(echo "* one two"; echo "[three four]") )
$ declare -p my_array
declare -a my_array='([0]="* one two" [1]="t")'
$ # What?
```

That's because I have a file called `t` in the current directory… and this filename is matched by the *glob* `[three four]`… at this point some people would recommend using `set -f` to disable globbing: but look at it: you have to change `IFS` and use `set -f` to be able to fix a broken technique (and you're not even fixing it really)! when doing that we're really *fighting against* the shell, not *working with the shell*.

```
$ mapfile -t my_array < <( echo "* one two"; echo "[three four]")
$ declare -p my_array
declare -a my_array='([0]="* one two" [1]="[three four]")'
```

here we're working with the shell!

Comment: This is great, I never heard about `mapfile` before, it's exactly what I've been missing for years. I guess recent versions of `bash` has so many nice new features, I should just spend a few days reading the docs and writing down a nice cheatsheet.

Comment: Btw, to use this syntax `< <(command)` in shell scripts, the shebang line should be `#!/bin/bash` - if run as `#!/bin/sh`, bash will exit with a syntax error.

Comment: Another side note, if you expect your `<( ... )` enclosed command might fail with an error, the error code is not propagated outside of the line. E.g. `mapfile -t my_array < <(false) || echo 'failed' >&2` would not echo `failed`, the place to add error checking then should be inside: `mapfile -t my_array < <(false || echo 'failed' >&2)` outputs `failed`. I wish there was an option to propagate the error code outside. `set -e -o pipefail` doesn't help.

Comment: Expanding on @GenePavlovsky's helpful note, the script must also be run with the bash command `bash my_script.sh` and not the sh command `sh my_script.sh`

Comment: @Vito: indeed, this answer is only for Bash, but this shouldn't be a problem, as strictly-compliant POSIX shells don't even implement arrays (`sh` and `dash` don't know about arrays at all, except, of course, for the positional parameters `$@` array).

Comment: `bash -v` tells you the version. OS X, sorry, MacOS is still on 3.2 (feb 2019)

Comment: As another alternative that doesn't require bash 4.0, consider `IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a my_array < <(my_command && printf '\0')` -- it both works correctly in bash 3.x, and also passes through a failed exit status from `my_command` to the `read`.

Comment: @GenePavlovsky - You've never heard of `mapfile` since it's a synonym for the more descriptive `readarray`.

Comment: For whatever reason, running this from the terminal works with `source`, but from a cron job, invoking only with `bash` works. When I `source` from a cron job, it says: syntax error near unexpected token `<'. Any idea why?

Comment: @CodingInCircles: not easy to answer with so little information. You can ask a new question where you can add more information and context.

Comment: As I see `mapfile -t my_array < <( my_command )` has exit status 0 if `my_command` fails.

Comment: For whatever reason I could not get the one liner with `read` to work with Bash 3.2 on MacOS, however the while loop works great.

Answer (score 113):

You can use

```
my_array=( $(<command>) )
```

to store the output of command `<command>` into the array `my_array`.

You can access the length of that array using

```
my_array_length=${#my_array[@]}
```

Now the length is stored in `my_array_length`.

### Handling expansion and spaces issues

To avoid expansion problems you can set the `IFS` env var as follows

- as suggested by @smac89 in the comments and other answers

```bash
IFS=$'\n' my_array=( $(<command>) )
```

Comment: What if the output of $(command) has spaces and multiple lines with spaces? I added "$(command)" and it places all output from all lines into the first [0] element of the array.

Comment: @ikwyl6 a workaround is assigning the command output to a variable and then making an array with it or adding it to an array. `VAR="$(<command>)"` and then `my_array=("$VAR")` or `my_array+=("$VAR")`

Comment: @Vito `VAR="$(COMMAND)"` doesn't need double quotes cuz variables made from a command substitution output already double-quotes the output implicitly, making it easier to double-quote things inside `COMMAND`.

Comment: @ikwyl6 If the input contains newlines, then do what the other answer suggested and change `IFS` to reflect that. `IFS=$'\n' my_array=( $(<command>) )`. This worked for me

Comment: What if you have a line containing only a `*`? You'll get a list of filenames in the current directory in your array.

Answer (score 24):

Here is a simple example. Imagine that you are going to put the files and directory names (**under the current folder**) to an array and count them. The script would be like;

```
my_array=( `ls` )
my_array_length=${#my_array[@]}
echo $my_array_length
```

Or, you can iterate over this array by adding the following script:

```
for element in "${my_array[@]}"
do
   echo "${element}"
done
```

Please note that this is the core concept and *the input must be **sanitized** before the processing*, i.e. removing extra characters, handling empty Strings, and etc. (which is out of the topic of this thread).

Comment: Terrible idea for the reasons mentioned in the answer above

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak "Above" and "Below" have no meaning in SO. Whose answer are you referring to?

Comment: Good point @Lou. I meant https://stackoverflow.com/a/32931403/2445864

Answer (score -1):

It helps me all the time suppose you want to copy whole list of directories into current directory into an array

```
bucketlist=($(ls))
#then print them one by one
for bucket in "${bucketlist[@]}"; do
echo " here is bucket: ${bucket}"
done
```