# List the available KVMs on Linux with a script

Tags: bash

I want to take the following "Names" from this command and put them in an array for a bash script, any ideas on the best way to do this?

```
    $ virsh -r -c qemu:///system list --all

     Id    Name                           State
    ----------------------------------------------------
    3     KVM_Win7-KVM                   running
```

EDIT:

The final result was this:

```
  declare -a kvm_list=( $(virsh -r -c qemu:///system list --all --name) )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First consider using the `--name` option to `virsh --list`, so you end up with:

```
virsh -r -c qemu:///system list --all --name
```

And then [reading output of command into array in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426529/reading-output-of-command-into-array-in-bash)