# Find a commit merging two ancestors

Tags: git

If I have a git tree that looks like

```
A---o---o---o
             \
              C---o---o---o---D
             /
    B---o---o
```

How do I find C given A, B and (if it helps) D? I guess this is somehow the opposite of `git merge-base`: that finds (roughly) the "latest common ancestor" of two commits, here I'm looking for the "earliest common descendant".

There could in theory be multiple candidates (e.g. if I added a commit directly merging A and B). But in this case there aren't, so I'm not worried about that situation.

Comment: `D` is not just helpful, it's *necessary*. Commits record only their parents, so from `A` it's impossible to "walk forward"; we have to walk backwards from something "ahead of" `A`. In any case finding `C` is a matter of finding the highest common commit, rather than lowest common ancestor, of paths in `git rev-list --ancestry-path A..D` and `git rev-list --ancestry-path B..D`.  If you generate the lists in reverse topo order and find an LCA from that, you'll get the commit you want, but Git does not have this built in.

Comment: Still, if the graph is simple enough, do the two `--ancestry-path --topo-order --reverse`s and the first commit that appears in both outputs is `C`. (You'll want to include revs `A` and `B` in these lists, in general, in case you have a degenerate graph where one of `A` or `B` *is* `C`.)

Comment: "D is not just helpful, it's necessary. Commits record only their parents, so from A it's impossible to "walk forward"; we have to walk backwards from something "ahead of" A." Ah yeah, I feel a bit silly for not realising this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to look at the list of commits `A..D` and `B..D`, and take the earliest line that appears in both lists.

You could use `comm` to keep the common lines of both histories

```
git log --ancestry-path --oneline A..D > /tmp/logA
git log --ancestry-path --oneline B..D > /tmp/logB
comm -12 /tmp/logA /tmp/logB | tail -1
```

One liner version :

```
comm -12 <(git log --ancestry-path --oneline A..D) <(git log --ancestry-path --oneline B..D) | tail -1
```

Comment: Yeah, I'd been hoping for something pre-existing, but this turned out to be easy enough to do. `diff -u <(git log --ancestry-path --oneline A..D) <(git log --ancestry-path --oneline B..D) | less`

Answer (score 1):

Well this is certainly an odd thing to look for, I'd love to know your use case for doing this frequently enough that you're looking for a command for it.

Regardless, the "simplest" way would be to just move backward through the history from D until you find what you want. I'm sure this can be improved, but here's a shell script that does what you want.

```
#!/bin/sh

startingCommit=$1
target1=$2
target2=$3

#https://stackoverflow.com/a/8574392/3980115
containsElement () {
        local e match="$1"
        shift
        for e; do [[ "$e" == "$match" ]] && return 0; done
        return 1
}

currentCommit=$startingCommit
resultCommit=$startingCommit
result=1

while true ; do
        echo "Trying $currentCommit"
        #https://stackoverflow.com/a/11426834/3980115
        list=( $(git rev-list $currentCommit) )
        if (containsElement $target1 "${list[@]}" && containsElement $target2 "${list[@]}"); then
                resultCommit=$currentCommit
                currentCommit=${list[1]}
                result=0
                continue
        else
                break
        fi
done

if [ "$result" ] ; then
        echo "Earliest descendent: $resultCommit"
else
        echo "No common commit found"
fi
```

Invoked from the command line with commit SHAs as:

```
./getDecesdent.sh D A B
```

Output:

```
Earliest descendent: C
```

---

I have no idea if this would work in a more complicated branching scenario, but I suspect it may will not get the correct result if any of the commits between D and C are merges - I honestly don't know.

However, this will find the correct commit in the situation described in the question - just very slowly. This script works by using `rev-list` to get all available commits from a given revision, and slowly works its way back through the history until it finds a commit that can't reach both targets. The older the target commits are, the slower this will be.

Comment: Thanks for this. I didn't end up using it - I found a way to do it in one line of bash without saving a script - but I appreciate the effort. I'm not actually doing this frequently, it just seemed like something I wanted to be able to do quickly in case I wanted it again in future. It doesn't seem that unusual to me, though since I've not used it before I guess it kind of is. In this case I just had two commits that seemed like the merge between them would be tricky, and I wanted to take a look at the merge.