# How to Save linux command output as list in variable

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

Below command is running on linux system and I want to save output as list.

```
root@Linux:~ kubectl get ns | awk '{print $1}'     
NAME
b2
b6
b7
cert-manager
```

I need to save above command output in to variable as list.

```
Example:- 
NAMESPACE = ['NAME', 'b2', 'b6', 'b7', 'cert-manager']

NAMESPACE is variable
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading output of a command into an array in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426529/reading-output-of-a-command-into-an-array-in-bash)

Comment: I am not sure to understand your question. Do you want to implement a command that is setting the variable `NAMESPACE` to the string `['NAME', 'b2', 'b6', 'b7', 'cert-manager']`, quotes, spaces and brackets included, or do you want to create a bash array `NAMESPACE` having as elements the 5 items you got above without quotes, brackets, spaces and newlines?

Comment: I need "kubectl get ns | awk '{print $1}' command out put as NAMESPACE(this could be any name) = ['NAME', 'b2', 'b6', 'b7', 'cert-manager']

Comment: @PierreFrançois this is the one i am looking "NAMESPACE to the string ['NAME', 'b2', 'b6', 'b7', 'cert-manager'], quotes, spaces and brackets included"

Comment: @Cyrus If possible can you explain the command ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is rather tricky because of the mix of quotes and double quotes where some need to be escaped, anyway next command appears to work:

```
NAMESPACE=$(kubectl get ns | awk 'NR == 1{o = "['\''" $1 "'\''"}NR > 1{o = o ", '\''" $1 "'\''"}END{o = o "]"; print o}')
```

With your input, this gives me:

```
$ echo "$NAMESPACE"
['NAME', 'b2', 'b6', 'b7', 'cert-manager']
```

Answer (score 1):

If the output includes only *simple* words you can write like this:

```
$ arr=( $( echo a b c d ) )
$ for i in "${arr[@]}"; do echo "$i"; done
a
b
c
d
$ arr=$( echo a b c d )
$ for i in $arr; do echo "$i"; done
a
b
c
d
$
```