# How do I list users who are currently logged into the system more than once?

Tags: unix

I know I can use finger command to display all the current users logged into the system. However, how can I list the users who are currently logged into the system more than once?

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems. Your Q **may be**  more appropriate for [su]  , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `w` command and parse its output

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
last | cut -d ' ' -f1  | sort |  uniq -c | grep -Ev 'reboot|wtmp'
```

`last` <-- last searches back through the /var/log/wtmp file (or the file designated by the -f option) and displays a list of all users logged
in (and out) since that file was created.

`cut -d ' ' -f1` <-- cut user name
`sort` -- Sort data
`uniq -c` <-- Get count of user
`grep -Ev` 'reboot|wtmp' <-- remove non required records

Answer (score 0):

A crude bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

arr=($(users))
tmp=${arr[0]}
cnt=1

for ((i = 1; i < ${#arr[@]}; ++i)); do
    if [ "$tmp" == "${arr[$i]}" ]; then
        cnt=$((cnt+1))
    else 
        if [ "$cnt" -gt "1" ]; then
            echo "${arr[$i]} is logged in more than once."
        fi
        tmp=${arr[$i]}
        cnt=1
    fi
done

if [ "$cnt" -gt "1" ]; then
    echo "${arr[$i]} is logged in more than once."
fi
```

Loop over an array created out of the output of `users` command.

Check if `tmp` is equal to the element coming after it:

if yes: echo,

else: change `tmp` to next element

**NOTE:**

`arr=($(users))` should be avoided generally, but for this particular problem is doesn't cause issues.

**SEE:**

[Reading output of a command into an array in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32931403/11590296)