# Bash Script - store find command output without spaces in variable

Tags: bash

I am looking to automate my xcode projects. It all works fine except the projects name with spaces. I have tried the following commands:

```
output_apps=`find ./ -name "*.app" -print`
output_apps=`find ./ -name "*.app"`
```

When I run

```
find ./ -name "*.app" -print
```

without storing into variable, it gives me output as expected as mentioned below:

```
.//Ten EU.app
.//Ten Official App EU.app
.//Ten Official App.app
.//Ten.app
```

However when I store the output of above command in a variable as below

```
output_apps=`find ./ -name "*.app" -print`
```

and then run the following for loop for get the names

```
for curr_app in $o
do 
    echo "$curr_app"
done
```

It shows

```
.//Ten
EU.app
.//Ten
Official
App
EU.app
.//Ten
Official
App.app
.//Ten.app
```

How do I maintain the spaces between each output and get the following output?

```
Ten EU.app
Ten Official App EU.app
Ten Official App.app
Ten.app
```

Comment: There are couple of solutions [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/how-to-loop-over-text-file-lines-within-bash-script-for-loop-522355/)... One with `while` loop and `read` is really noteworthy.

Comment: the while loop worked when the names are extracted from the filename. However, I am extracting the required files after pipe redirection from xcodebuild command. 

Is there a way to put find as input in the while loop?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you don't need to store the file names in a variable, you can use [`find -print0`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) in combination with [`xargs -0`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs). This separates the found entries by NUL bytes instead of newlines. `xargs` reads these NUL separated values and calls some command with as many arguments as possible.

```
find ./ -name "*.app" -print0 | xargs -0 some-command
```

If you want, you can limit the number of arguments given to `some-command` with `xargs -n 1`

```
find ./ -name "*.app" -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 some-command
```

Yet another approach is to read the files with a `while` loop

```
find ./ -name "*.app" -print | while read f; do
    some-command "$f"
done
```

This calls some command with one file at a time. The important point is to enclose the `$f` into [double quotes](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Double-Quotes).

Comment: Thanks @Olaf. The first two queries brings result
`.//Ten EU.app .//Tenn Official App EU.app .//Ten Official App.app .//Ten.app`. I will try to put them in an array as suggested by ormaaj. If that fails, I will just create a temp file, put values and read it from there as suggested by zplesivcak. There is a lot more code and this small part has taken forever.

Comment: How to put them in array?

Comment: @vvn One way would be to use the while loop and add the values one by one. See also question http://stackoverflow.com/q/1951506/1741542

Answer (score 1):

The file names may contain spaces. You need to ask find to separate them via `NULL(\0)`. Use `find -print0`.

Comment: No force in the known universe can put a NUL byte into a bash variable.

Comment: I am sorry, I couldn't interpret your answer into complete command. I tried output=`find ./ -name "*.app" -print0`. How do I adjust NULL(\0)

Comment: @Vebz It isn't a complete answer. First you need the nonstandard (but common) `-print0` feature (it's a good thing). Then you need a way to read NUL-delimited streams (Harder. Also generally not possible without non-standard extras. Have a look at Bash's `read -d`). If you need to store the results, you'll want to use an array.

Comment: A complete example would be `for i in $(find -print0 | xargs -0 echo); do echo $i; done`

Comment: @alinsoar your method brings the same result as mine. (Even when I add double quotes to "$i".

Comment: @ormaaj I will give it a try and post my answer if I get success. Thanks