# Bash: Append to list with variable name

Tags: bash, shell

The first three commands work but the fourth does not. How can I append to an array with a variable in its name?

```
i=4
eval pim$i=
pim4+=(`date`)

pim$i+=(`date`)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you targeting bash 4.3 or newer? If so, there's a shiny new feature targeted just at this use case. :)

Comment: Incidentally, this is the topic of BashFAQ #6: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006

Comment: I'm trying to go off of this SO response but use a variable variable name: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1951523

Comment: By the way -- if the second line is meant to initialize the array, `declare -a "pim$i"` would be a better way to do it; `eval pim$i=` isn't actually specifying any type, array or otherwise

Comment: Also, how would I get the length of the array with a variable array name? `${#pim4[@]}` works but `${#pim$i[@]}` does not.

Comment: ...with eval, `eval 'pim_count=${#pim'"$i"'[@]}'` will do the trick. The usual caveat about needing to trust your `$i` to not be malicious if you're substituting it into an `eval`'d string applies -- if it's data you're getting from a file, a socket, user input, etc., this would be a bad idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With bash 4.3, there's a feature targeted at just this use case: namerefs, accessed with `declare -n`. (If you have a modern `ksh`, they're also available using the `nameref` built-in)

```
declare -n pim_cur="pim$i"
pim_cur+=( "$(date)" )
```

With bash 4.2, you can use `printf -v` to assign to array elements:

```
array_len=${#pim4[@]}
printf -v "pim4[$array_len]" %s "$(date)"
```

Prior to bash 4.2, you may need to use eval; this can be made safe by using `printf %q` to preprocess your data:

```
printf -v safe_date '%q' "$(date)"
eval "pim$i+=( $safe_date )" # only safe if you can guarantee $i to only contain
                             # characters valid inside a variable name (such as
                             # numbers)
```

Comment: The bash 4.3 answer is along the lines of what I'm looking for but I don't have bash 4.3 and thus no nameref.

Comment: Why are the other two answers unsuitable?

Comment: The last answer helped, thanks Charles! I used: eval "pim$i+=(\`date\`)" which I think does the trick.

Comment: @user1837378, for a date specifically, it might be okay. For anywhere the data could possibly be malicious or unsafe (and that includes filenames), you need to do the `printf %q` hoopla or you risk introducing security bugs.

Comment: @user1837378 ...think of adding a filename to a list using eval when that filename is `/tmp/i am a bad person/$(rm -rf /)`.