# bash incrementally adding to an array

Tags: arrays, bash, indexing, parameter-passing, whitespace

Consider the code below

```
#! /bin/bash

declare -a input # unnecessary
declare -a bad
declare -a good # unnecessary

input=('alpha 23' 'bravo 79' 'charlie 12')
echo "input is " ${#input[@]} "long"
for x in "${input[@]}"
do
    bad=$x
    good[ ${#good[@]} ]=$x
    echo 
    echo "added '$x', good is now " ${#good[@]} "long, bad is still " ${#bad[@]} "long"
done
```

The output is

```
input is  3 long

added 'alpha 23', good is now  1 long, bad is still  1 long

added 'bravo 79', good is now  2 long, bad is still  1 long

added 'charlie 12', good is now  3 long, bad is still  1 long
```

According to the man-page for bash ... "When  assigning  to  indexed arrays, if the optional brackets and subscript are supplied, that  index  is  assigned  to; **otherwise  the  index  of  the  element  assigned is the last index assigned to by the *statement* plus one**.  Indexing starts at zero."

I clearly don't understand the part in bold because I expected the statement "bad=$x" to auto-increment the index every time it is executed. It doesn't and is assigning to bad[0] every time.

Why isn't it doing what I expected and is there a better way of writing the code than the clumsy line where I assign to good[ .. ]

Comment: see: [Bash: add value to array without specifying a key](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1951506/3776858)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

choroba has answered my question, the correct code would be

```
#! /bin/bash

input=('alpha 23' 'bravo 79' 'charlie 12')
echo "input is " ${#input[@]} "long"
for x in "${input[@]}"
do
    output+=("$x")
done

echo "output = (" ${output[@]} ") and is " ${#output[@]} " long "
```

It is useful for scanning and processing the list of parameters to a script if the parameters have spaces and other awkward characters within them

Answer (score 4):

The part you quoted relates to assignment, not addition:

```
array=([0]=zero [1]=one [2]=two)
```

is equivalent to

```
array=([0]=zero one two)
```

which, in fact, is the same as

```
array=(zero one two)
```

To add to an array, use `+=`:

```
array+=(three)
```

Comment: That makes more sense now, thanks. If I replace bad=$x  in the code above with bad+=("$x") then I get the answer I want.