# Add multiple values from console using shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I want to send multiple values from console so that individual
values are assigned to array indexes in array. Later I can use foreach
loop to get those values. Thank you.

**example:**

```
 Enter values from 1 to 4:
 1
 2
 3
 4

 arr[0] = 1,
 arr[1] = 2,
 arr[2] = 3,
 arr[3] = 4
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

*If I give you directly the whole answer, you will not learn anything. Therefore  I will give you the building blocks necessary to build the solution and guide you through the building steps.*

1) Append to array in bash:

```
ARRAY=()
ARRAY+=('A')
ARRAY+=('B')
```

Have a look at: [Bash array append](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951506/add-a-new-element-to-an-array-without-specifying-the-index-in-bash?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

2) `read` syntax:

```
read [options] NAME1 NAME2 ... NAMEN
```

Have a look at: [read command](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_08_02.html)

3) Bash loop construct:

```
while read elem
do
  #If end of inputs (special value for example)
  #break in order to quit the loop
  #do something (append to array)
done
```

Have a look at: [Bash loops](http://www.compciv.org/topics/bash/loops/)

4) Bash branching (if/else/elif/...) construct

Have a look at: [Bash if/else](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_02.html)

5) Last step, you need to put everything together:

Create an empty `array`, `loop` on the user input, check the input value via a `if` and `break` the loop if it reach a specific condition, otherwise add it to the array

**Let me know if you are stuck somewhere, I will help you.**