# Adding elements in a Bash array to print them later

Tags: linux, bash

I am adding elements on an array ([Add a new element to an array without specifying the index in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951506/add-a-new-element-to-an-array-without-specifying-the-index-in-bash)) but I am getting an unexpected result. I suppose I am doing something wrong when adding elements in the array and/or when iterating the array to print its values.

Code:

```
for name in $(cat list.txt); do
    host $name.$DOMAIN | grep "has address" | cut -d" " -f4
done

for name in $(cat list.txt); do
    echo "."
    IPS+=(`host $name.$DOMAIN | grep "has address" | cut -d" " -f4`)
    echo ${#IPS[@]}
done

for ip in $IPS; do
    echo "IP: $ip"
done
```

Output:

```
12.210.145.45
67.20.71.219
75.58.197.10
31.70.88.22
.
1
.
3
.
4
.
4
.
4
IP: 12.210.145.45
```

Expected output:

Output:

```
12.210.145.45
67.20.71.219
75.58.197.10
31.70.88.22
.
1
.
2
.
3
.
4
IP: 12.210.145.45
IP: 67.20.71.219
IP: 75.58.197.10
IP: 31.70.88.22
```

Comment: See [DontReadLinesWithFor](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) re: the `for ip in $(cat ...)` idiom, and also the related [BashPitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).

Comment: Similarly, `addr=$(host "$name.$DOMAIN" | grep "has address" | cut -d" " -f4)"; if [[ $addr ]]; then ips+=( "$addr" ); fi` would be more reliable. (Does assume you fix your variable case, but that's a thing you should do).

Comment: That said, replacing `host` with `dig +short` would make this whole thing a lot simpler; do that and you don't need to mess with `grep` or `cut` at all.

Comment: Very interesting. Thanks for the pointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To iterate over an array, use

```
for ip in "${IPS[@]}" ; do
```

See PARAMETERS in `man bash`.

Comment: Great thanks. Is there a reason why the logged "." is appearing more than 4 times? including the logged size as: 1, 3, 4, 4 instead of the expected 1,2,3,4.

Comment: maybe `host $name.$DOMAIN | grep "has address" | cut -d" " -f4` returns more than one word?

Comment: `printf 'IP: %s\n' "${array[@]}"` is much shorter.

Comment: This line must be failing to add to the list: `IPS+=(\`host $name.$DOMAIN | grep "has address" | cut -d" " -f4\`)`.  If list.txt has 4 lines of input and one of the lines has a space in it, you are going to loop 5 times.  Try adding `echo "$name"` into one of the loops to see. Also, you can check out any error messages by adding `2>> error.txt` to the end of `host $name.$DOMAIN | grep "has address" | cut -d" " -f4`  Error messages will display in error.txt

Comment: @Jason, ...the lack of quotes when you add an item means you aren't guaranteed that only (and at most) one will be added per iteration.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, That is true as well.  I was referring to why he is looping the second loop 5 times.

Comment: Oh, I see, I think the .txt is making it looping 5 times. But why the size of the array is printed as "1,3,4,4,4"?  I think it should be "1,2,3,4,4,...."

Comment: Think you could provide the contents of list.txt?

Comment: I found it. So silly. It is because there can be more than one addition to the array per loop. So it is logical. I just expected that the command after `IPS+=` was getting only ONE result, but it can return more than one comma separated. Thanks all

Comment: @Jason: No, that would concatenate a string, not add a new element to an array.

Comment: ...see my comment on the question showing where the quotes *should* go (`ips+=( "$addr" )`).

Comment: =D Yeah.  I misunderstood your comment. So if he wanted to do that in one line (without the blank check) he would do `ips+=("$(...)")`?