# Bash Global Array

Tags: arrays, bash

I want to have a global array, each time I call the function cal on Main, I can add a new element on array arr_var

```
function cal () {
# Some operation
while true; do
  read -p "would you like asignment ? on ${var} " yn
  case $yn in
    [Yy]* ) arr_var+=$var
    [Nn]* ) break;;
     * ) echo "Please answer yes or no.";;
  esac
# Some operation
done
}

# Main
eval arr_var=()
cal "aa"
cal "bb"
cal "cc"
```

That I want

```
printf '%s\n' "${arr_var[@]}"
aa bb cc
```

but I get

```
aabbcc
```

Comment: See: [Add a new element to an array without specifying the index in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1951506/3776858)

Comment: @Inian, without the spaces around `+=` -- `arr_var+=( "$var" )`

Answer (score 1):

Don't use eval for that...

```
arr_var=()
```

or

```
declare -ag arr_var
```

eval is evil : [Why should eval be avoided in Bash, and what should I use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529220/why-should-eval-be-avoided-in-bash-and-what-should-i-use-instead)

And you have you answer in the comments :

```
var=()
var+=(a)
var+=(b)
declare -p var
```